# Konnte nicht vs hätte nicht können

Tags: modal-verb

Was is der Unterschied zwischen diesen Sätzen?

- Ich konnte es nicht tun
- Ich hätte es nicht tun können

Und wann wird jeder verwendet?

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Was hat die bisherige Recherche ergeben? Was ist die eigene Vermutung?

Comment: Interessanter wäre der Unterschied zwischen "ich habe es nicht ändern können" vs. "ich konnte es nicht ändern".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In dem ersten Fall warst du kurz davor es zu tun, hast es dann aber doch nicht getan. Im zweiten Fall kam es gar nicht erst soweit. Du wurdest also gar nicht erst auf die Probe gestellt. Ein Beispiel:

Deine Mutter sagt dir: Wenn ich nicht rechtzeitig von der Arbeit komme, dann musst du alleine von der Schule nach Hause fahren.

1.Fall: Deine Mutter schafft es nicht rechtzeitig von der Arbeit zu kommen. Du hast aber deine Fahrkarte vergessen. Deswegen kannst du nicht selber nach Hause fahren. Später sagst du zu deiner Mutter: Ich konnte es nicht tun (weil ich meine Bahnkarte vergessen hatte).

2.Fall: Du hast wieder deine Fahrkarte vergessen. Aber deine Mutter schafft es rechtzeitig von der Arbeit. Die Notwendigkeit, alleine nach Hause zu fahren, besteht also gar nicht. Also sagt du später zu deiner Mutter: Ich hätte es nicht tun können (weil ich meine Bahnkarte vergessen hatte).

Ich hoffe ich konnte weiterhelften.

Answer (score 2):

Der Unterschied besteht in der Fähigkeit und der Möglichkeit.

- `Ich konnte es nicht tun`

  - Ich hatte keine Fähigkeit dazu, ob Möglichkeit ist egal.
  - D.h. auch, dass "Fähigkeit" den Fall einbezieht, dass ich psychisch nicht fähig war.
- `Ich hätte es nicht tun können`

  - Ich hatte keine Möglichkeit, Fähigkeit wahrscheinlich schon.
  - D.h., ich war physisch nie in der Lage, es zu tun.
  - Auch verwendet mit "selbst wenn ich gewollt hätte, hätte ..." => hier deutlich, dass auch eine psychische Bereitschaft nicht ausgereicht hätte, zum damaligen Zeitpunkt der (unbedingte) Wille fehlte.

Es ist nicht völlig auszuschließen, dass beide Satzkonstruktionen genau andersrum verwendet werden. Denn entscheidend ist die Botschaft, die der Empfänger versteht und die hängt sehr vom Kommunikationsverhalten aller Beteiligten ab.

Es lässt sich einwenden, dass "wo ein Wille, da ein Weg" gelte, womit jedes "ich konnte nicht" als "ich wollte nicht" ausgelegt wird. Daher die Inklusion von "psychischer Fähigkeit".

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt zwei Möglichkeiten, wie der Konjunktiv interpretiert werden kann. Welche Möglichkeit zutrifft, hängt vom Kontext ab, und zwar davon ab, *ob ich es tun konnte*.

### Ich konnte es tun

Der zweite Satz verträgt sich mit der Aussage "Ich konnte es tun" und bedeutet in diesem Fall:

> Ich konnte es tun, aber ich hätte es [unter bestimmten Umständen] nicht tun können.

### Ich konnte es nicht tun

Der zweite Satz verträgt sich auch mit der Aussage "Ich konnte es nicht tun". In dem Fall negiert er (zusätzlich) auch noch die Möglichkeit, *dass ich es hätte tun können*. Er bedeutet also:

> Ich konnte es nicht tun, und ich hätte es auch unter bestimmten Umständen nicht tun können.

Die beiden Sätze unterscheiden sich in diesem Fall nicht in ihren [Denotaten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotat#Denotat_als_der_bezeichnete_Gegenstand). Das heißt, jede Situation, die mit

> Ich konnte es nicht tun.

beschrieben werden kann, kann ebensogut mit

> Ich hätte es nicht tun können.

beschrieben werden. In dieser Hinsicht sind die Sätze synonym.

Der Unterschied besteht im Konnotat. Die Verwendung des Konjunktivs eröffnet einen (nicht näher spezifizierten) Möglichkeitsraum. Man würde erwarten, dass der Konjunktiv eine hypothetische, kontrafaktische Bedingung einleitet, um diesen Möglichkeitsraum zu definieren, wie etwa in:

> Ich hätte es nicht tun können, *selbst wenn* man mir eine Million dafür geboten hätte.

Wird eine solche Bedingung nicht explizit genannt, dann wirft die Verwendung des Konjunktivs automatisch die Frage nach dieser Bedingung auf. Mir scheint dadurch [implikatiert](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implikatur) zu werden, dass hier *jede Bedingung* eingesetzt werden kann. In meinen Augen hat der konjunktivische Satz also die Konnotation:

> Ich hätte es *unter keinen Umständen* tun können.

Die Verwendung des Konjunktivs ohne die Benennung der Bedingung scheint mir daher konnotativ eine Verstärkung der zum Ausdruck gebrachten Unmöglichkeit zu sein.

Wie stark diese Konnotation empfunden wird, kann aber subjektiv sehr verschieden sein. Diese implikativen Konnotationen sind selten sehr eindeutig und können auch durch dialektale oder soziolektale Konventionen überschrieben werden.

Comment: Kannte "Implikatur" bisher nicht. Warum nicht "implizieren"? Dient zumindest als Wortherkunft (https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Implikatur)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Man verwendet das Verb "implikatieren", um auszudrücken, dass es sich um eine Implikatur handelt, nicht um eine Implikation. _Implikatur_ ist ein Terminus Technicus, der eine engere Bedeutung hat als _Implikation_, siehe den verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikel, genauer siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implikatur#Terminologie_(Übersetzung)

Comment: *Ich konnte das Problem lösen* versus *ich hätte das Problem lösen können*. Einmal hat der Sprecher das Problem gelöst, einmal nicht; es liegen also zwei verschiedene Situationen vor, entgegen der Ausgangsannahme.

Comment: Ah, diese Deutung habe ich gar nicht gesehen. Das ist natürlich ein wichtiger Unterschied. Da war ich wohl ein bisschen betriebsblind. Ich ändere das mal noch :)